# Creating COM Component Using CreateProcess and CoCreateInstance

Tags: c++, com

Is there any issue with starting a COM component exe using CreateProcess followed by CoCreateInstance (using the class ID from CLSIDFromProgID) ?

I have done this and it seems to work but am getting side effects on closing down.
Sometimes it closes down properly, sometimes (when looking through Process Explorer), the process stays active but moves in the tree.

Sorry for being vague but what I'd like to know is whether it's legitimate to start a COM object in this way (CreateProcess then CoCreateInstance) or whether the only way to properly achieve this is just to call CoCreateInstance?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Quote: "Bad idea btw, a COM server should not be a console mode app".  Use CoGetObject() repeatedly until it no longer fails.  Beware that you cannot predict how long it is going to take for the process to start running and publish its class factories, you'll have to work from a worst-case of no less than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Only `CoCreateInstance`. Why do you wanna bother with `CreateProcess` at all?

Comment: Basically, I need to redirect stdout and stderr of the created COM exe object at the outset.  So I used CreateProcess to redirect this stdio then called CoCreateInstance.

Comment: It would be ideal if I could specify where to redirect stdout and stderr at CoCreateInstance but I don't know how to do that or if it's possible.  Any ideas?